# lower bound for being far away from the mean

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $S = \sum^n _{i=1} S_i$ be a sum of n independent random variables,
each attaining values $+1$ and $−1$ with equal probability. Let $P(n,Δ) =
Pr [S > Δ]$.

Prove that for $Δ ≤ n/C$,
$P(n,Δ) ≥ \frac{1}{C} exp(\frac {-Δ^2}{Cn}) $
,
where C is a suitable constant.

i really don't know how to approach this problem.

is there any hint?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can directly apply the special case of Chernoff bounds to this problem. A loose upper bound can be derieved from Chebyshev's inequality as well.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand you,which do mean "special case of Chernoff bounds"?because Chernoff just gives me upper bound.

Comment: Read the section on special case here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound

Comment: that has nothing with var(S),why  "Note that μS=0μS=0 and Var(X)=n"? thank u

Comment: I started writing an answer for Chebyshev's that requires $Var(X)$ but later realized you were asking for Chernoff. I am removing that now.

Comment: chernoff just gives:$P(n,Δ)<exp(\frac{-\Delta^2}{2n})$,how to get lower bound?